# JSON deserializer returns "null" for Collection type in REST api @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, serialization

I Have a rest controller that is not de-serializing the array type in json..

```
@PostMapping()
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Team> createteam(@RequestBody Team team) throws JsonProcessingException {

    Team savedTeam = teamService.createTeam(team);
    return new ResponseEntity<Team>(savedTeam, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

below is my entity class.

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Developer> developers;


    
    public Team(String name, List<Developer> developer) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.developers = developer;
    }


    public Team() {
        super();

    }
    


    public List<Developer> getDeveloper() {
        return developers;
    }


    public void setDeveloper(List<Developer> developer) {
        this.developers = developer;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and my other entity..

```
package com.demo.springbootdemo.entity;

   
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Developer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Team team;
    private Long phone;
    private String name;

    public Developer() {
        super();
    }

    public Developer(Team team, Long phone, String name) {
        super();
        this.team = team;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public Long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

below is my JSON payload, which returns null "developers" when i call the post method.i have tried changing the number of properties in json payload but, still i am not able to figure out why my json is not de-serilaized to List of developers..

```
    {
    
    "id": 1004,
    "name": "claim",
    "developers": [
        {
            
           "id" :1,
            "phone": 9092123,
            "name": "raina"
        }
        
        
    ]
}
```

Comment: any error logs or something?

Comment: No .I'm just getting null values for developers..the remaining payload for teams is properly deserialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what Deserializer are you using, but with the [Jackson ObjectMapper](http://org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper) I solved it changing the method names of the getter and setter for the `developers` properties: they should be called `setDevelopers` and `getDevelopers`. In your code they are called `setDeveloper` and `getDeveloper`, without the final S.

To avoid problem like these, I just add Lombok as a dependency and it takes care of creating setters and getters.

With [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) your Team class would look like this:

```java
// ... more imports here...
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Developer> developers;    
}
```

You may need to add more Lombok annotations for generating constructor methods according to your needs.